# how to set height of imageview as parent height dynamically?

Tags: android, listview, height, imageview

I have a listview in my app. The size of the listitems are different. 
When I click on a button in the listitem a semitransparent image has to be displayed on that particular listitem. Since the size of the listitem is different I could not set the the height of the imageview as fixed size.

I have set it as match parent, but the problem is that it is taking only the initial height of the listitem, i.e the height of imageview is smaller than the listitem height. To solve this issue I have set the height of the imageview as parent height(list item layout). After trying this the above mentioned issue is fixed but another issue arises.

The new issue is coming when I scroll the listview. When I click on the button in the list item it is displaying the imageview correctly, but after scrolling the size of the imageview it's varying. I could not find the reason for this.

Given below is my code. This is from my adapter class.

```
        holder.parentLayout.setTag(R.id.viewPos,Integer.valueOf(position));
        holder.fadeView.setTag(R.id.viewPos, Integer.valueOf(position));

        int height=holder.parentLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
        holder.fadeView.getLayoutParams().height=height;
```

Comment: if your ImageView is part of List Row item and when you up down list it will recycle so you need to manage height of ImageView again .

Comment: and show your getView Method.

Comment: this code is a part of getView() method.actually that methos is big..thats why i ddnt post full method here

Answer (score 0):

you have to change image size using following method
in this method change bitmap size as per your height and width

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, double newHeight, double newWidth) 
{
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();

        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,matrix, false);

        return resizedBitmap;
}
```

set bitmap(resizedBitmap) in  your imageview on listview